# AngularJS - Error: [$injector:pget] Provider 'function ()' must define $get factory method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, get, provider

I am a newbie in AngularJS. I am doing an example from Pro AngularJS book by Adam Freeman, but got stuck with this error.

```
Error: [$injector:pget] Provider 'function ()' must define $get factory method.
```

I'm at the point where I have to create a Cart Widget and a summary partial view. Above error is thrown when AngularJS is trying to load the Cart module.

Here's the partial error message from Chrome developer tools. The author doesn't mention anything about the $get function or provider at this point. Not sure what am I doing wrong. Please help.

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module sportsStore due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module cart due to:
Error: [$injector:pget] Provider 'function ()' must define $get factory method.
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.23/$injector/pget?p0=function%20()
```

Cart widget code.

```
angular.module("cart", [])
.factory( function() {

    var cartData = [];

    return {

    addProduct: function (id, name, price) {
        var addedToExistingItem = false;
        for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
            if (cartData[i].id == id) {
                cartData[i].count++;
                addedToExistingItem = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!addedToExistingItem) {
            cartData.push({
                count: 1, id: id, price: price, name: name
            });
        }
    },

    removeProduct: function (id) {
        for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
            if (cartData[i].id == id) {
                cartData.splice(i, 1);
                break;
            }
        }
    },

        getProducts: function () {
            return cartData;
        }
    }
})
.directive("cartSummary", function (cart) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl: "components/cart/cartSummary.html",
        controller: function ($scope) {

            var cartData = cart.getProducts();

            $scope.total = function () {
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                    total += (cartData[i].price * cartData[i].count);
                }
                return total;
            }

            $scope.itemCount = function () {
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < cartData.length; i++) {
                    total += cartData[i].count;
                }
                return total;
            }
        }
    }
});
```

here's how it's getting called from the app.html

```
<script>
    angular.module("sportsStore", ["customFilters", "cart"]);   
</script>
<script src="controllers/sportsStore.js"></script>
<script src="filters/customFilters.js"></script>
<script src="controllers/productListControllers.js"></script>
<script src="components/cart/cart.js"></script>
```

....

```
<body ng-controller="sportsStoreCtrl">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">SPORTS STORE</a>
        <cart-summary />
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" ng-show="data.error">
        Error ({{data.error.status}}). The product was not loaded.
        <a href="/sportsstore/app.html" class="alert-link">Click here to try again</a>
    </div>
    <ng-include src="'views/productList.html'" />
</body>
```

SportsStore Module code..

```
angular.module("sportsStore")
    .constant("dataUrl", "http://localhost:5500/products")
    .controller("sportsStoreCtrl", function ($scope, $http, dataUrl) {

        $scope.data = {}
        $http.get(dataUrl)
            .success(function (data) {
                $scope.data.products = data;
            })
            .error( function (error) { 
                $scope.data.error = error;
            });
 });
```

Comment: Can you post the code for module sportstore?

Comment: Added sportsStore module code.

Comment: I was doing a silly mistake. I had missed the first argument from following function call. .factory("cart", function(). But when I posted the question, I took it from the wrong location in my application, which was correct. I really apologize for this. I'll update the posted code so it reflects the correct issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a module defined as "cart" somewhere, looks like there may be an issue with referencing the "cart" in the module when you are trying to define a factory.  If you are trying to reference your main app try something like:

```
var main = angular.module("sportsStore", ['cart'])...
```

Then to define your cart factory try:

```
main.factory('cart', function() {... cart factory code here...})
```

Answer (score 0):

try this 
remove in module []
  and your module name is not cart 
cart change to sportsStore

```
     angular.module("sportsStore")
.factory("cart", function() {     ... })
```

Comment: Hi Harutyun, actually I am not doing any http call from that function. I have updated the code above.

Comment: you difined ng-app="sportsStore" in html ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62779/discussion-between-harutyun-abgaryan-and-pak).

Answer (score 0):

Try this your code for your cart.js file as yours is different from how it is in the book:

```
angular.module("cart", [])    
.factory("cart", function () {...}
```